# How to convert python byte string containing a mix of hex characters?

Tags: python

Specifically, I am receiving a stream of bytes from a TCP socket that looks something like this:

```
inc_tcp_data = b'\x02hello\x1cthisisthedata'
```

The stream using hex values to denote different parts of the incoming data. However I want to use the inc_data in the following format:

```
converted_data = '\x02hello\x1cthisisthedata'
```

essentially I want to get rid of the b and just literally spit out what came in.

I've tried various struct.unpack methods as well as .decode("encoding). I could not get the former to work at all, and the latter would strip out the hex values if there was no visual way to encode it or it would convert it to character if it could. Any ideas?

Update:

I was able to get my desired result with the following code:

```
inc_tcp_data = b'\x02hello\x3Fthisisthedata'.decode("ascii")


d = repr(inc_tcp_data)

print(d)
print(len(d))
print(len(inc_tcp_data))
```

the output is:

```
'\x02hello?thisisthedata'
25
20
```

however, this still doesn't help me because I do actually need the regular expression that follows to see \x02 as a hex value and not as a 4 byte string.

what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

I've solved this issue by not solving it. The reason I wanted the hex characters to remain unchanged was so that a regular expression would be able to detect it further down the road. However what I should have done (and did) was simply change the regular expression to analyze the bytes without decoding it. Once I had separated out all the parts via regular expression, I decoded the parts with `.decode("ascii")` and everything worked out great.

I'm just updating this if it happens to help someone else.

Comment: why do you care about the b?

Comment: because i have to use regular expressions to parse the data and it doesn't work unless it is a regular string. It throws an exception otherwise. 
`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using python 3

```
>>> inc_tcp_data.decode('ascii')
'\x02hello\x1cthisisthedata'
```

Comment: I've tried this and when I print out the encoded string, it completely removes the hex character: `inc_tcp_data = b'\x02hello\x1cthisisthedata'  

d = inc_tcp_data.decode('ascii')  

print(d)`

Comment: Which version of python you are using? And what did you see from your `print(d)`?

Comment: using python 3.3 print(d) produced `hellothisisthedata`

Comment: The characters \x02 and \x1c are invisible and that's why you cannot see them from `print`. Try `print(str(d))`

Comment: I get the same output with `print(str(d))`. If I change the hex character to a visible one like `\x3F` it converts it to the ascii `?` but I want it to stay as `\x3F`